# c# create xml from byte array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

i have xml what i get as byte array, whats the best way to get the xml string out of it? I was tryng to use xmltextreader and memorystream but with no success..

Comment: Where do you get the byte array from? Do you know the encoding used?

Comment: XML containes base64 encoded data..

Comment: I meant the [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of the XML document.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

OR

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
doc.Load(ms);
```

This assumes your data has UTF8 encoding which is the usual for XML. Also `buffer` here is the byte array.

Comment: Good answer, although the MemoryStream is IDisposable so don't forget to wrap it in a using block! :)

Comment: because of a byte order mark (BOM) I found this overload more useful (thanks Jon Skeet) 
`MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, true);`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your xml is in the default 'UTF8' encoding., you could do something like this;

```
string xml = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
System.Xml.XmlDocument xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument().LoadXml(xml);
```

Or this;

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    doc.Load(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the Encoding, you can do

```
string xmlString = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

and use the string

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlString));
```

Comment: Ooops... GetBytes takes a string and gives an array of bytes. GetString takes an array of bytes and gives a string. FTFY.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [System.Text.Encoding.UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) class. It should let you convert youre byte array into a UTF8 string.

Comment: See [XML Encoding Defaults](http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm) page here. UTF8 is the correct assumption is most cases.

Comment: Still, I think you should have a note about it on your answer.