# Parse byte array into XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, parsing

I have a serial communications protocol with several commands, all of which are specified in a text file.  I have a library that provides a basic method of communicating, but I want to add parsing without having to hard-code all of the structures specifying the packet formats.  From what I've found, this may be possible using XML or JSON, but I don't know where to start.

An example of a command format specified in my text file would be something like:

```
[255]
Name = Get Relay State
Param1 = Relay Number, uint8_t
Result1 = Relay State, uint8_t
```

So, the byte array a request of this command to get relay 1 would be `FF 01` and its response would be something like `FF 00` (indicating the relay is open).

This is a highly simplified example as there are hundreds of these commands, each with numerous inputs and outputs.

Is there some way I can extract the values, field names, and command name without explicitly declaring a `struct` for every input and output in each command?  I've done that with several so far but even with using code generation tools it is not flexible to changes in the protocol.

Comment: This might help you get a feeling for your question.

See: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582155/c-sharp-create-xml-from-byte-array)

Comment: If you really want a strongly typed assembly built around your protocol definition, you'll want to look at Reflection.Emit()  You will need to parse your file (XML or other) and write code to generate the C# library based on these values.  It shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Mangist That's exactly what I wanted to avoid having to do.  Do you know if there are any alternatives besides Reflection.Emit or CodeDOM?  I can't help but think that there is a more trivial solution out there.

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986947/how-to-map-json-string-to-the-calling-of-c-sharp-method

Comment: @L.B Very clever solution to that question!  I did not realize that was possible with reflection.  I may be able to do something similar to solve this, but I'm going to try `TypeBuilder` from `Reflection.Emit` first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class I wrote to parse in a serial protocol that you define.  I haven't tested this code, so it may require a few tweaks to get it running.  This is based on the XML schema I have defined below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<protocol>
  <!-- Get Relay State (255) -->
  <command name="GetRelayState" value="255">
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="RelayNumber" type="Byte"/>
    </parameters>
    <results>
      <result name="RelayState" type="Byte"/>
    </results>
  </command>

  <!-- Get Voltage (254) -->
  <command name="GetVoltage" value="254">
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="CircuitNumber" type="Short"/>
    </parameters>
    <results>
      <result name="Voltage" type="Single"/>
      <result name="MaxVoltage" type="Single"/>
      <result name="MinVoltage" type="Single"/>
    </results>
  </command>
</protocol>
```

Here is the C# code

```
public class ProtocolManager
{
    public event Action<Command> ResponseReceived;

    // This will read the XML definition of your protocol into a Protocol object
    public Protocol BuildProtocol()
    {
        var protocol = new Protocol
        {
            Commands = new List<Command>()
        };

        var xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
        xmlFile.Load(
            Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Protocol.xml"));

        var protocolElement = xmlFile["protocol"];

        foreach (XmlNode command in protocolElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            // Load the command definition
            var comm =
                new Command
                {
                    Name = command.Attributes["name"].Value,
                    Value = int.Parse(command.Attributes["value"].Value),
                    Parameters = new List<Parameter>(),
                    Results = new List<Result>()
                };

            // Load the list of parameters
            foreach (XmlNode p in command.SelectSingleNode("parameters").ChildNodes)
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        Name = p.Attributes["name"].Value,
                        ParamType = Type.GetType(p.Attributes["type"].Value)
                    });
            }

            // Load the list of expected results
            foreach (XmlNode p in command.SelectSingleNode("results").ChildNodes)
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        Name = p.Attributes["name"].Value,
                        ParamType = Type.GetType(p.Attributes["type"].Value)
                    });
            }

            protocol.Commands.Add(comm);
        }

        // You should now have a complete protocol which you can bind to UI controls
        // such as dropdown lists, and be able to parse
        return protocol;
    }

    // This will test the incoming stream for responses (packets)
    public void TestProtocol(SerialPort port, Protocol p)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50); // Give the port 50ms to receive a full response
            bytesRead = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // For the sake of simplicity assume we read the whole packet in a single read and we don't 
            // need to look for message encapsulation (STX, ETX).
            var commandValue = buffer[0];
            var command = p.Commands.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Value == commandValue);
            if (command == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    String.Format("Unknown command received {0}", commandValue));
            }
            // Read result parameters
            int index = 1;
            foreach (var r in command.Results)
            {
                // Here you need to implement every data type you are expecting to receive
                // I have done 2
                switch (r.ResultType.Name)
                {
                    case "Byte":
                        r.Value = buffer[index];
                        index++; // Reading only a single byte
                        break;
                    case "Short":
                        r.Value = (float)(buffer[index] >> 8 | buffer[index]);
                        index += 2; // Reading a 16bit short is 2 bytes
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException(
                            String.Format("Unknown response type {0}", r.ResultType.Name));
                }
            }

            // Notify listening client that we received a message response
            // and it will contain the response parameters with values
            var evt = ResponseReceived;
            if (evt != null)
            {
                evt(command);
            }

        } while (bytesRead > 0);

        // End of read / wait for next command to be sent
    }
}

// Represents your serial protocol as a list of support commands 
// with request/response parameters
public  class Protocol
{
    public List<Command> Commands { get; set; }

    // Used to data-bind to comboboxes etc.
    public List<string> GetCommandNames()
    {
        return Commands.Select(c => c.Name).OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
    }
}

// A single command with a name, value and list of request/response parameters
public class Command
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type ParamType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type ResultType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I'll throw it into a solution to test it out.

Comment: It works great.  This will be a nice guide for writing one for my particular application.